# In KVM/Libvirt: How can I have two NAT networks with the same IP range on one host?

Tags: networking, qemu, kvm, libvirt

I'm trying to use KVM and libvirt to test some infrastructure setup in a virtual machine, where basically I'm booting a VM inside a network.

In my case, this VM and the network always must have the same static IP configuration (e.g. network 192.168.125.0/24, with the VM IP 192.168.125.50).

Now I was wondering if I could run two such tests in parallel on the same host. However, in that case libvirt doesn't allow me two create two NAT networks with the same IP range simultaneously.

Is there a way to work around that limitation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible, but you're going to need to handle all the network setup yourself. The basic process will look something like:

1. Manually create a couple of bridge devices. Give them distinct ip addresses that (a) are on different networks and (b) are **not** on the 192.168.125.0/24 network.
2. Create a namespace for each virtual network and link it to the corresponding bridge with a `veth` interface. Give this interface (a) the address 192.168.125.1/24 and (b) an address on the same network as the associated bridge.
3. Run a `dnsmasq` service in each namespace configured to serve out DHCP addresses for the 192.168.125.0/24 network. Either configure static entries for your vms (requiring you to set static MAC addresses on your VMs when you create them), or just configure it to hand out a single address.
4. Set up masquerading rules in the namespace to masquerade traffic from the 192.168.125.0/24 network.

All of that will look something like this:

```
#!/bin/sh

ip link add br-net1 type bridge
ip link add br-net2 type bridge

ip addr add 10.10.10.1/24 dev br-net1
ip addr add 10.20.20.1/24 dev br-net2

ip link set br-net1 up
ip link set br-net2 up

ip netns add net1
ip netns add net2

ip link add net1-ext type veth peer name net1-int netns net1
ip link add net2-ext type veth peer name net2-int netns net2
ip link set net1-ext master br-net1 up
ip link set net2-ext master br-net2 up

ip -n net1 addr add 192.168.125.1/24 dev net1-int
ip -n net1 addr add 10.10.10.10/24 dev net1-int
ip -n net1 link set net1-int up
ip -n net1 route add default via 10.10.10.1

ip -n net2 addr add 192.168.125.1/24 dev net2-int
ip -n net2 addr add 10.20.20.10/24 dev net2-int
ip -n net2 link set net2-int up
ip -n net2 route add default via 10.20.20.1

ip netns exec net1 iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 192.168.125.0/24 -j MASQUERADE
ip netns exec net2 iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 192.168.125.0/24 -j MASQUERADE

rm -f /tmp/net1.{log,pid}
rm -f /tmp/net2.{log,pid}

ip netns exec net1 \
  dnsmasq -C /dev/null -k --dhcp-range 192.168.125.50,192.168.125.50 \
  --log-facility /tmp/net1.log --log-dhcp \
  --pid-file=/tmp/net1.pid \
  &

ip netns exec net2 \
  dnsmasq -C /dev/null -k --dhcp-range 192.168.125.50,192.168.125.50 \
  --log-facility /tmp/net2.log --log-dhcp \
  --pid-file=/tmp/net2.pid \
  &
```

None of these changes are persistent, so a simple reboot will clean everything up.

---

With the above configuration in place, I can start a virtual machine on `net1` like this:

```
virt-install \
  --cloud-init ssh-key=/home/lars/.ssh/id_rsa_default.pub  \
  --disk pool=default,size=10,backing_store=jammy-server-cloudimg-amd64.img,backing_format=qcow2 -n ubuntu.net1.virt -r 4096  \
  --import  \
  --osinfo ubuntujammy  \
  --noautoconsole \
  --network bridge=br-net1
```

Or on `net2` like this:

```
virt-install \
  --cloud-init ssh-key=/home/lars/.ssh/id_rsa_default.pub  \
  --disk pool=default,size=10,backing_store=jammy-server-cloudimg-amd64.img,backing_format=qcow2 -n ubuntu.net2.virt -r 4096  \
  --import  \
  --osinfo ubuntujammy  \
  --noautoconsole \
  --network bridge=br-net2
```

Both machines will have the address `192.168.125.50` address. I can ssh into these machines by running `ssh` in the appropriate namespace:

```
sudo ip netns exec net1 ssh -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa_oddbit root@192.168.125.50
```

With this configuration, the machines are able to access my *host*, but they don't have general outbound access. To enable that would require a couple of additional `MASQUERADE` rules on the host.